# showing each table data row as a Label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having following `FinanceProductFeatures` table , I want show each of this table record as label name for a form.

[image]

So I created model class like this

```
public class ProductFinanceFeatures
{
    public IList<AB_FinanceProductFeatures> ListProductFinanceFields { get; set; }
}
public partial class AB_FinanceProductFeatures
{
    public string ProductFinanceNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFinance_Value_EN { get; set; }        
}
```

then Controller class like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Financing_Product_Feature_Configuration()
{
    var model = new ProductFinanceFeatures
    {
        ListProductFinanceFields = db.FinanceProductFeatures.ToList()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

then Its viewpage like this

```
@model albaraka.Models.ProductFinanceFeatures

@{

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFinanceFields.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinanceNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinance_Value_EN, new { @row = 5 })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

but here I'm not getting expected result, cannot render the Label

showing like this

[image]

Comment: you may want to use this overload : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_7

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: have you tried HTML.Displayfor ?
use HTML.Displayfor instead of HTML.LabelFor

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: To what fields in the database did you map the properties in `AB_FinanceProductFeatures`. And what's their content?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to see ProductFinanceNameEn name as values of `FinanceProductFeatures` tables `NameEn` fields

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinance_Value_E, Model.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinanceNameEn)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke for an example 

`Finance Type  : TextArea`

Comment: If the value of `ProductFinanceNameEn` is `"Finance Type"`, then the code in my previous comment will do just that :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I replaced following code `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinanceNameEn)` with 
`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinance_Value_EN, Model.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinanceNameEn)` seems like this is not fetching values , any wrong with my linq query ?

Comment: I don't know what `FinanceProductFeatures.ToList()` returns - you will need to debug that yourself (does your table field `NameEn` map to your `ProductFinanceNameEn` property?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke do i need map that one too ? how can I do that ?

Comment: I don't know - you have not given enough information :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke do I need map inside `var model` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107529/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score -1):

Just simply replace `TextAreaFor` with `DisplayFor` as below-

```
<div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinance_Value_EN, new { @row = 5 })
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.ListProductFinanceFields[i].ProductFinance_Value_EN)
</div>
```

Hope this works for you..!

Comment: How is *that* supposed to change the identical displayed values "ProductFinanceName"?